# Django: per-customer customizations

Tags: django, customization

We have a Django project that suits all our needs. Now we have to give it to a customer which wants some customizations.

Is it possible to keep these customizations in a separate application without putting specific code in the core project? Are there some best practices to do that?

I think it is easy to customize templates (by adding an entry in `settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS`) and views (by mapping custom urls), but I'm wondering how to make customizations on models (with db changes) and forms (e.g. to add some custom validation).

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize Django's ["site" framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/sites/) for most of these.

Models can inherit from the original. They're usually fetched in views, which you would adapt anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will want to re-architect your original app to facilitate extending it. This will pay off in other areas though so it's probably worth the effort.

Look at some of the methods used to extend and customize contrib.admin. It's a good example of an app that's been designed with fairly good potential for extension and customization and it uses a variety of techniques.